# Azure Media Services - Blob not appearing in Asset using Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

I want to use Azure Rest API to encode a video to multiple bitrates.

Here are the steps i am following:

1. Uploaded single MP4 video as an asset using Azure Portal.
2. Received **access_token** from **Azure AD Token for Service Principal Authentication** using Postman.
3. Used this token to create a new asset using Postman.
4. Created a new Transform request using Postman.
5. Created a new job using the Transform request with input as the file uploaded at step 1 and output as asset created at step 3 using Postman.

Now this job appears under the "Jobs" section of Azure Media Service. After the job is successfully complete, the blobs are present in the blob container.

But those files are not appearing in the Asset (created at point 3 above). An empty asset is present even after the job is complete.

Do i need to call another API after the job is complete to map the blobs to the asset?

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Media Services currently offers two API versions, v3 and v2. The Azure Portal, as called out [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/migrate-from-v2-to-v3), is using the older/legacy v2 APIs. When you use Transforms and submit Jobs using that Transform, you are using the v3 API - the resultant output Asset is meant to be a v3 entity. Hence, contents of that Asset are not going to show up in the Azure Portal. If you are using a PC, there is a tool [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Media-Services-Explorer/releases/tag/v5.0.0.16) that is being built on top of the v3 APIs, which may be of help in browsing v3 Assets.

Comment: Thanks Anil for the help. I'll use the PC tool you have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Note for folks returning to this post, we are removing the Postman collection for the v3 API and directing customers to use the client SDKs directly instead now.  The reason being is that too many customers had issues with "rolling their own" retry policy code for Azure Resource Management and also had trouble implementing the long running operation support for async operations.  We prefer that most customers of Media Services now use the client SDKs available for various languages. See this page for various samples by client SDK language.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/samples-overview